# Can I use an AAV instead of a vent pipe for a remote sink?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent, crawlspace, venting

Our General Contractor added a "temporary" sink in our lower level during our kitchen remodel on the main level.  It is the perfect location for a kitchenette downstairs, which has 2 bedrooms, one bathroom at the far end, and a family room with separate entrance from the main level (it is a "walk-out" basement).

The area behind the sink is an unfinished "crawl" space (7 to 8 ft. high, used for storage and my workshop) with ventilation via foundation vents. The contractor installed an AAV on a vertical ABS pipe behind the wall, in the "crawl" space. It is impossible to add a vent pipe upward through the main level at that point.  Due to the construction of the house, there is no way to vent upwards for at least 20' laterally from that pipe.

I understand the longest horizontal run for a drain vent is 5' for the 2" drain line, and a 45 deg. rise (which I understand is acceptable as "vertical") won't get me anywhere near a place I can vent upward through the roof or to other vertical vent pipes.  There is nowhere else downstairs a kitchenette can be installed without completely demolishing, redesigning and rebuilding the downstairs space.

Can I utilize the AAV as pictured (or another such as the Oatey Sure Vent) instead of a vertical vent through the roof for the sink?  The sink drains to the main sewer stack about 30 ft. away. It has been working fine for several years.  It is fully accessible in a space that you can stand up in for service. The house is located in California.

Comment: When an AAV is working properly it doesn't vent _into_ anywhere. It's an Air _Admittance_ Valve; its purpose is to break vacuum/suction that can sometimes occur in a drain system by allowing air to be sucked into the pipe. The AAV should never allow sewer gases to escape into the space around the AAV.

Comment: thank you Greg.  I should change the title of my post to "can I use an AAV in lieu of a vertical vent pipe" for a remote sink. I understand I want/need air to come in to enable water to flow down the pipe.  Oatey claims their Oatey Sure Vent meets International Plumbing Code and Uniform Plumbing Code for this purpose, but I'm concerned that in Contra Costa County, California that a building inspector won't allow it.

Comment: If that's your concern, you need to ask Contra Costa County to be sure. They are allowed here.

Comment: It seems you're confusing length limits for the "trap arm" vs limits for the vent. Vents should rise "vertically" until they are above the flood level of the fixture, but then can go horizontally for very long distances (depending on the pipe size). Even below the flood level, vents can be horizontal if structural conditions demand it. AAV's have been allowable under the UPC for a very long time, and are widely used.

Comment: Yup, this is mostly reading as being confused about vents and the vent rules. Vents must rise "vertically" (which really means 45°-90°) until "6 inches above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served", or sometimes "on the branch served." At that point they can and do run long distances "horizontally" which is actually 2% slope to the drain, not horizontal. Trap arms and vents have different rules.